# Why isn't SHOW ERRORS logging the SQL Exception being thrown in MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, exception

In a MySQL stored procedure, I am handling SQL exceptions with this:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
    BEGIN
        SELECT "SQL exception occured." AS "SQL Exception";
        SHOW ERRORS;
        SHOW WARNINGS;
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
```

I know that an exception is being thrown because the `SQL exception occured` message is being displayed and the transaction gets rolled back.  However, nothing is populated in the `SHOW ERRORS` or`SHOW WARNINGS` tables.  Why is this, and how can I tell which SQL exception is being thrown?

Here is the SQL statement that's causing the mystery exception:

```
SELECT IF(count(*) = 0, TRUE, FALSE) 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='myDatabase' 
AND TABLE_NAME='exam';
```

EDIT:

[Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13423266/1245897) has informed me that the exception is being swallowed up by the handler.  So how do I find out what the exception is and still rollback? In a java catch block, I can see the exception by using `Exception.getMessage()` or `Exception.printStackTrace()`. Is there a similar feature in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a handler for `SQLEXCEPTION`, the exception is consumed - it's considered "handled" so there is no longer an "exception".

If your stored procedure flow depends on a particular exception, you must declare a handler for a particular [SQLSTATE error code](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-messages-server.html), eg

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE `23000`
```

Actually, all handlers are actually of this form, because:

- `SQLEXCEPTION` is shorthand for the class of `SQLSTATE` values that do not begin with `'00'`, `'01'`, or `'02'`
- `SQLWARNING` is shorthand for the class of `SQLSTATE` values that begin with `'01'`
- `NOT FOUND` is shorthand for the class of `SQLSTATE` values that begin with `'02'`

Comment: I see.  So how do I find out what the exception is and still rollback?  In a java `catch` block, I can see the exception by using `Exception.getMessage()` or `Exception.printStackTrace()`.  Is there a similar feature in MySQL?

Comment: @CFL_Jeff You can't. See edited answer for a possible way forward.

Comment: I have edited my question to show the SQL statement that is causing the exception.  Do you see anything wrong with it, or can you recommend some `SQLSTATE`s for me to look for?

Comment: excellent answer. by the way, how can you get the sql exception on the declare---handler block to, for e.g., insert the message on your own error table? If you have the answer please advise here or even better on my question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28506/mysql-get-info-from-show-errors

Thanks!